# Preparing Linux Template CentOS/RedHat 7

Tags: linux, templates, centos

I'm want to build a Linux template for CentOS/RedHat 7.

I did it before with CentOS/RedHat 6 by following the [instruction](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualiza%20tion/3.0/html/Evaluation_Guide/Evaluation_Guide-Create_RHEL_Template.html), which contain like:

```
# touch /.unconfigured
# rm -rf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
# ifdown eth0
* Remove the HWADDR entry in the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
# ifup eth0
* edit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
# poweroff
```

Those instruction do not work for me with CentOS/RedHat 7.

In 6, after I turn the template on it ask for: Language, root password, network configuration and etc.

In 7, it restart the server as usual like after regular boot and the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160  not updated with the correct HWADDR.
(The file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules not exist in 7)

I tried also to follow the [instruction](https://serverfault.com/questions/626889/what-is-the-recommended-method-to-prepare-red-hat-centos-7-templates):

```
systemctl enable initial-setup-graphical.service
systemctl enable firstboot-graphical.service
> /etc/sysconfig/firstboot
```

From 2 first command I got the error:

```
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
```

and the path to the firstboot not exist.

I remove one user I added - with no help.

Any idea how I can build template for CentOS/RedHat 7?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I saw, in RedHat7, in the file: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rhel-configure.service there is reference to /.unconfigured. I also tried to change the file it excute in /lib/systemd/rhel-configure and add him 'passwd root'

Comment: Sorry, Full comment:: In RedHat7, I saw in file: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rhel-configure.service there is reference to /.unconfigured. So I tried to change the file it execute, in /lib/systemd/rhel-configure and add him, for test, 'passwd root' with no success. It not remove the /.unconfigured file and not tun the passwd command at boot.   How the file rhel-configure.service work?